# How to read sim card details in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to read the sim card details on the boot of the phone. How can I do that,is it possible???

Answer (score 6):

I highly doubt it's possible to read SIM card details from a Windows Phone app. But either way, it is impossible to launch an application at boot time.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone is a closed operating-system; currently, you cannot add any app that will be launched on boot of the phone (as you can with a windows service), what you have are application background services that will run whenever the OS wants it to run!

Furthermore, the current SDK (version 7.1.1) doesn't allow you to access any information of the SIM Card...